# how to make my discord bot give me role after sending message?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

hello i am making a bot that will give you role when you type in message
but my code doesnt work it always gives this error

File "Rgiver.py", line 32, in on_message
role = discord.utils.get(server.guild.roles, name="Admin")
NameError: name 'server' is not defined

here is my code

```
async 

def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    if member.bot:
        return
    if message.attachments:
        return
    print(message.content)
    print(str(message.author))


    if "role" in message.content:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Giving role.", color=0x00ff40)
        await message.channel.send(message.channel, embed=embed)
        role = discord.utils.get(server.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `server.guild.roles`, you probably mean `message.guild.roles`

Also, your `add_roles` usage is wrong, see the docs for [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles), you probably mean `message.author.add_roles(...)`